# issue with if-else in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the railstutorial and now got into the point where header will change dynamically depending on whether the user is logged in or not, using a conditional dropdown as shown below

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">
<%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
<nav>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
    <% if logged_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Account <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
    <% end %>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is the logged_in? method defined in the helper

```
module SessionsHelper

# Logs in the given user.
def log_in(user)
 session[:user_id] = user.id
end

# Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
 def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
 end

# Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
 def logged_in?
  !current_user.nil?
 end
end
```

For some reason this is not working, although I have copied the tutorial exactly. I am not sure if the line (if_logged_in?) is not being called or it is called but returns false. The else block gets executed by the way

I was wondering if there is anyway I can check if the method defined in the helper (logged_in?) is working and gets called correctly? Something like printing an output from the method itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to check whether that method's being called, and what's happening in it, is to throw a debug statement in there, like so:

```
def logged_in?
  Rails.logger.debug("\n\n *** logged_in? #{current_user}")
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

You load the page and then look at your development log and see if that line is there, and whether the user exists.

For more details about debugging, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. At least I am able to trace the problem now